# When the last row in a DataGridView is selected, a value from the previous row is returned instead of from the selected row

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView on a form which is populated by a dataset. Everything works except one thing. In the first column I have id numbers. The user clicks on some row, and the id number from the column is taken to be deleted from the db. Every id is taking correctly except the last row - it is a new row, as you know, because the user can create new records in the database. Anyhow, if the user makes a mistake and selects this row, my code shown below somehow gets the id number from the previous row. I don't know how to avoid that issue. I am taking it using this code:

```
dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
```

---

Edit:
**i've added code i am using to better understand the situation:**

Form Load event:

```
   Private Sub FrmNewRodzaj_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                Dim del As DelegateGridRefresh = New DelegateGridRefresh(AddressOf FillGrid)
                Dim del2 As DelegateGridRefresh = New DelegateGridRefresh(AddressOf AlignGrid)
                del = [Delegate].Combine(del, del2)
                AddHandler EventGridRefresh, AddressOf del.Invoke
                del.Invoke()
            End Sub
```

Fill Grid method:

```
Private Sub FillGrid()
        NewRodzaj = New MachineRodzaj()
        dgv.DataSource = NewRodzaj.GetRodzaje.Tables(0)
    End Sub
```

GetRodzaje method:

```
 Public Function GetRodzaje() As DataSet
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from tbMachRodzajList", con)
        con.Open()
        GetRodzajeDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        GetRodzajeDataAdapter.Fill(GetRodzajeDataSet, "trial1")
        Return GetRodzajeDataSet
    End Function
```

AlignGrid method:

```
  Private Sub AlignGrid() 
        dgv.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue 'LightSkyBlue 
        dgv.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue  
        dgv.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None             
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = True
        dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 9)

        Me.dgv.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.dgv.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow

        Me.dgv.RowHeadersVisible = False

        Dim column0 As DataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns(0)
        column0.Visible = False
        Dim ColNazwa As DataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns(1)
        ColNazwa.HeaderText = "Nazwa"
        ColNazwa.[ReadOnly] = False
        Dim ColOpis As DataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns(2)
        ColOpis.HeaderText = "Opis"
        ColOpis.[ReadOnly] = False
        Dim column3 As DataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns(3)
        column3.Visible = False

        dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill

        Dim dgvColumnHeaderStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle()
        dgvColumnHeaderStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dgvColumnHeaderStyle

        'You cannot change the column and row header colours without disabling visual styles:
        dgv.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
        ' Set the row and column header styles.
        dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
        dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Firebrick
        dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 14)

    End Sub
```

button method to save/update data:

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnZapisz.Click
        NewRodzaj.MakeChanges()
        RaiseEvent EventGridRefresh()
    End Sub
```

MakeChanges method:

```
Public Sub MakeChanges()
        MachineRodzajDAO.GetRodzajeMakeChanges()
    End Sub
```

GetRodzajeMakeChanges method:

```
  Public Sub GetRodzajeMakeChanges()
        If Not GetRodzajeDataSet.HasChanges Then
            MessageBox.Show("No changes no need to update", "Informacja", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else

            Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(GetRodzajeDataAdapter)
            Dim i As Integer
            Try
                i = GetRodzajeDataAdapter.Update(GetRodzajeDataSet, "trial1")
                MsgBox("Updated" & i & " records")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub
```

so the one is missing and i am fighting with is delete button after user select row to be deleted from db and click delete button, if he select newRow then message should appear - you selected wrong row. The id values are placed within column(0) when i use CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value if user click newRow then id is id of before row so i cannot just make check if value is nothing and also IsNewRow not working.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUsun.Click


    End Sub
```

Hope now will be clear enough

Comment: try to disable something like "autoadd row" ..

Comment: what do you mean? If you about to delete last new row then no i need that.

Comment: There should be something like if dgv.isnewrow  ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i also checked that if  dgv.CurrentRow.IsNewRow but its seems to not working i always going to else clause whether i am selecting newrow or not.

Comment: maybe some solution would be to check if selected row is last one?

Comment: You have to notify that you cannot have a new row in databound DGV ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually isNewRow works great

put it on Event dgv.CellClick for example

```
 If dgv.CurrentRow.IsNewRow Then
        'Cancel your code
 Else
        'Execute your code
 End If
```

Edit: then check the row index like

```
dgv.NewRowIndex
```

that will always be the NewRowIndex

so if a user clicks a row or NewRow that row will become CurrentRow

you could then check stuff like

```
    If dgv.CurrentRow.Index = dgv.NewRowIndex - 1 Then
        'User clicked NewRow but CurrentRow is the one before the NewRow
    End If
```

Edit: actually this is pretty straight forward

but you have to know what is happening on your DGV.

1.
user clicks `NewRow` and the `ClickedCell` just gets selected then u get the correct RowIndex with

```
dgv.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex
```

which is the same as

```
BenutzerDataGridView.NewRowIndex
```

and `CurrentRow.Index` will always be -1

2. User clicks `NewRow` and start typing. Now `NewRow` moves one Row down and the Row which is being edited becomes `CurrentRow`.

that's why i added the above to always ensure that it is not the `NewRow`

```
If dgv.CurrentRow.Index = dgv.NewRowIndex - 1 Then
```

this should actually be enough to do what you want ^^

last EDIT:

```
    If dgv.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex = dgv.NewRowIndex Then
        MsgBox("wrong row")
    End If
```

or this way

```
     If dgv.Rows(dgv.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
            MsgBox("wrong row")
     End If
```

i'm glad u got it sorted out ^^

Comment: its working when i associate it as you did to cellclick directly. The problem is i have couple button on form for adding, deleting and for other operation so i cannot associate just to cellClick event directly. User can check the row and then click delete button but can also use new row to add new data. How to overcome this issue then other way?

Comment: it goes inside if when i click newrow but unfortunetly when i click on row before newrow its also going into if... (dont know if matter but datagrid is bounder to dataset.tables(0) )

Comment: by the way when User clicked NewRow the CurrentRow is the one before the NewRow ??

Comment: of course i think you have a logic problem in your application. when You said user can check the row. If it is a checkboxColumn on the row and user clicks the NewRow then a new new row will be added. and NewRow moves 1 row down. Better show what you are doing cause this i leading nowhere when you have event logic problems in your application

Comment: ok let me then past some more code as its working on my side in main post ok?

Comment: this is not checkbox column. If user decided to delete something he selecting row containing some data and then delete button to delete. If he selected NewRow then he should received info that this is not proper row to be deleted. Thats why i was trying to use IsNewRow to check that but it always giving me previous value of before row.

Comment: so user clicks into NewRow is there a new empty row created and NewRow goes 1 row down?  or NewRow stays selected? is it FullRowSelect?

Comment: I hided RowHeaders and its not fullrow select. if user double click on newrow cell (first or second ) and start to type something then second newrow is appearing below.

Comment: actually it is not a second NewRow...there is always only 1 NewRow.

Comment: btw Why do they start typing something into a cell in NewRow when you are deleting it?

Comment: Nocturnal this part of code works perfectly fine, there is only one grid, user can start to fill out newrow or even next one and then clicks Save button and everything is going to database correctly, also if user edit something and click Save button its ok. Problem is if user decide to select row to delete it then i need to check out if this is not NewRow otherwise take column0 value and delete.

Comment: i edited my answer but actually it is very clear how to do it you just have to know what is allowed on your DGV and what not. With above examples you can do anything  you want to accomplish you just have to case it

Comment: i've putted your code inside btnDelete_Click : "If dgv.CurrentRow.Index = dgv.NewRowIndex - 1 Then" - your if executing either user selects NewRow or row before as well. so unfortunetly not working.

Comment: hehe sry but this is so lol. of course it is ....then change it to If BenutzerDataGridView.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex = BenutzerDataGridView.NewRowIndex Then msgbox("wrong row")...i'm out have a nice day

Comment: haha that was the asnwer ! I dont know how i missed that !! :) thank i give you the as asnwer. By the way why isNewRow was not working, or value from column(0) was pointing to row vefore?? Please put also this line to your answer :)